# In Angular, using *ngFor inside *ngIf not working

Tags: angular

So I have some code

```
<div class="square positive" *ngFor="let square of getEquipmentHealth()"></div>
```

This prints boxes one after the other, but if I add an if condition,

```
<div *ngIf="getEquipmentHealthNumber() <= 3" >
  <div class="square positive" *ngFor="let square of getEquipmentHealth()"></div>
</div>
```

This prints the boxes one below another

I am new to angular and maybe missing something simple. Would anybody know why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `*ngIf`is for [tag:angular], *not* [tag:angularjs].

Comment: ok thankyou..fixed the tag..would you know why the first stmt works as expected, but adding an if doesnt

Comment: When you say "it prints the boxes one after another", what do you mean? Did you just want them side by side? Are you able to reproduce it in a StackBlitz?

Comment: @Aparna what does this print: <div><div class="square positive" *ngFor="let square of getEquipmentHealth()"></div></div>

Comment: To make sure that the `*ngIf` does not affect your layout, use: `<ng-container *ngIf="getEquipmentHealthNumber() <= 3" >...</ng-container>`.

Comment: "it prints the boxes one after another" means side by side..but when I add the if statement, it prints it one below the other

Comment: the <ng-container> fixed it!!!..thankyou @ConnorsFan..you are awesome!!!..please post an answer so that I can give you credit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the container with the `ngIf` directive, the additional `div` may cause the style rules to apply differently to the inner `div`. To eliminate the outer `div`, use the Angular `ng-container`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="getEquipmentHealthNumber() <= 3" >
  <div class="square positive" *ngFor="let square of getEquipmentHealth()"></div>
</ng-container>
```